# Which android application directory is better to save data in,External Files directory or External cache directory

Tags: android, save, xamarin.android

I wanna to save some files as saved searches or saved items(some binary files and images) in my android application and also i want that by uninstalling application this files also remove from users device.I'm using monondroid to developing application and had understood that in each applications external directory, there is two directories. one by name 'cache' and other by name 'files'.
Question is that in witch directory should i save my files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think It Depends on Your Application that what you need.[Check Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) you will be clear where to use External File Directory and External Cache Directory.

External Cache Directory's Files will be removed when you uninstall your appplications while External File directory's files will not be affected.

Comment: but in the page that you recommend witted that files directory also will deleted after uninstalling application ! :-S

Comment: yeah but if you are using API level 8 or greater.

Comment: i using android 2.2 for my app. therefore it will be deleted.yes?